# KSQL multiple keys

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Created table with multiple keys

```
CREATE TABLE base_mcc 
 WITH (KEY_FORMAT='AVRO',VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO',
       PARTITIONS=2)
 AS
SELECT  mcc , cnt_id,SUM(`amount`) AS `sum_amnt` 
FROM STREAM WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 90 DAYS) \
GROUP BY `mcc `,`cnt_id `,`mcc` 
emit changes;
```

after creation topic I see only value (sum_amnt), but I need write to sink table value and keys. Is it possible write keys with values to table (Postgres) using sink connector?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple keys"? A Table can only have one "key column". Yes, JDBC Sink connector can write the primary key column and value schema fields as columns

Comment: I created table and topic created with keys from columns in group by section

Comment: Okay, and your connector configuration looks like what? Are you getting any errors when you try writing to Postgres?

Comment: PK mode for table 'table' is RECORD_VALUE with configured PK fields [key], but record value schema does not contain field: field

Answer (score 1):

solved by replacing parameter "pk.mode": "record_key"